# Finding certain elements when only able to ask in chunks

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of $n$ elements. Of these elements $b\ll n$ are blue and $r=n-b$ are red. I want to find all blue elements.

My only way to discriminate between red and blue objects is by asking a blackbox that takes a fixed number $k$ of elements (with $n \gt k \gg 1$) and returns an approximation of how many of those elements are blue. The approximation is such that the returned number $\hat N_b = N_b + u$ is the real number of blue elements $N_b$ combined with a Gaussian noise $u$ that has a Variance of $\text{Var}(u)\approx 1$ and an expected value of $E(u)=0$. $k$ is big enough that in a random sample the expected number of blue elements $E(N_b)$ greatly exceeds the variance of the noise.

Is there an efficient algorithm to determine (to a certain probability) which elements are blue?

Comment: "I'm pretty certain the noise prevents me from ..." - if noises between different queries are independent, you can always make enough queries to make the noise negligible (make the same query multiple times and take an average).

Comment: That's true, thank you. I'll edit that part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the noise.  Any time you make a query, repeat it 1000 times, use the average of the 1000 responses, and round it to the nearest integer.  The noise in the result before rounding will have variance $1/1000$, so the probability that rounding creates an error is $\operatorname{erfc}(\sqrt{125})$, which is less than $10^{-54}$... i.e., negligibly small (smaller than the probability that a cosmic ray strikes your computer and causes it to give an incorrect result).  This will increase the number of queries by a factor of 1000, i.e., by a constant factor, so it will not affect the asymptotic complexity.

Now once there is no noise, it becomes much easier to solve it.  For instance, you can first find a set of $k$ objects known to be red, then repeatedly randomly sample $n/b$ unknown objects, add $k-n/b$ known-red objects, and query the result; if the response is 1, then you know that one of those is blue, and you can use binary search to find it.  This will require about $O(b \log b)$ queries.  I expect it should be possible to reduce this to $O(b)$ with more cleverness, but I haven't figured that out yet.  A good question is whether you can do substantially better than $O(b)$, if $k \gg b$.